# Unbuffered I/O is not working

Tags: c++

I have this program that is supposed to disable buffering for `std::cout`. I want to print out what I've written to the output device, but when I print `str` nothing comes out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0);
    std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::unitbuf);

    std::cout << "Hello, World\n";

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::cout.rdbuf();

    std::string str{ss.str()};

    std::cout << str; // nothing
    // str.size() == 0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0);
```

This doesn't necessarily do anything because `cout` isn't specified to use a `std::filebuf`.

```
std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::unitbuf);
```

This *clears* the `unitbuf` bit so I/O is *not* unbuffered. Calling `setf` instead should request unbuffered I/O as desired.

```
ss << std::cout.rdbuf();
```

This attempts to *read* cout so it will extract nothing.

Just relying on `setf( std::ios::unitbuf )` [works as expected](http://ideone.com/wSkgev):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    std::cout.setf( std::ios::unitbuf );

    std::cout << "Hel";
    write( 1, "lo, wo", 6 );
    std::cout << "rld!\n";
}
```